# javascript document.getElementById().value works only with numbers not with strings

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have an AJAX based application that updates a text field in a form depending on user input. The text field is defined as follows:

```
<%= form.text_field :queue, {:class => "queue_class", :id => "queue", :size => 40} %>
```

the Javascript code is the following:

```
document.getElementById('queue').value = <%= @returned_value %>
```

If in the controller, I set @returned_value to a number, like:

```
@returned_value='77777777777'
```

then is works fine. But if I set it to a string value like:

```
@returned_value='abcxyz'
```

then it does not work, the text field is not updated and I don't get any error message, it's like it does nothing.

I also tried this:

```
document.getElementById('queue').innerHTML = <%= @returned_value %>
```

but it does not work with any returned value, neither when `@returned_value='77777777777'` nor when `@returned_value='abcxyz'`

Can someone please point me to what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotes around the ERb expression:

```
document.getElementById('queue').value = '<%= @returned_value %>';
```

(And it should be JavaScript-escaped as well.)

A number is a legal JavaScript expression without quotes. Arbitrary strings aren't; JS will try to parse it as an expression (reference) plus whatever else is in the string that's relevant to JS.

Comment: @rh4games No problem. Just make sure to JS-escape it to avoid additional issues.

Comment: Sorry Dave, how to "JS-escape"?

Comment: @rh4games With [`escape_javascript` (docs)](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/escape_javascript).

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the string from within JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('queue').innerHTML = '<%= @returned_value %>';
```

Numbers get coerced to strings via `.toString()`, but unquoted strings will throw a parser error.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code is generated as a string which is later pasred by the javascript interpreter. Thus,. if you generate strings, you have to put quotation marks around it like so:

```
document.getElementById('queue').value = '<%= @returned_value %>'
```